# Getting output amount of tokens when swapping on UNI v3 in Solidity

Tags: uniswap, solidity-0.8.x

I would like to evaluate multiple swap paths in Solidity using Uni v3. Is it possible to get the amount of tokens received before actually executing the swap?

I am aware this will probably cost a lot of gas but this is not that big of a deal in my scenario. I am just wondering whether it's even possible without modifying the state.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that there is a Quoter contract in v3-periphery which can be used exactly for this.

[Here](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/lens/Quoter.sol#L106) is the method which returns the quoted output amount.

Comment: NB: quoteExactInput is a write function but you can call it without paying any gas fees by using callStatic from the ethers library

Answer (score 0):

The Uniswap router has the function `getReverse`, which receive the paths `[fromToken, toToken]`, and amount of input token.

This functions returns the `[amountIn, amountOut]`, which can be used as a reference for the amount of token to be received.

Comment: Hello, this sounds like exactly what I need. Which router implements this? It doesn't seem to be implemented in the official [Uniswap routers](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/SwapRouter.sol) I checked. Thank you

Comment: You're looking at v3 of uniswap router, which extended from router V2. So take a look at V2, you will se function: `getAmountsOut`  [doc here](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#getamountsout)

Comment: v3 swap router isn't extending v2 as is obvious from [the contract definition](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/464a8a49611272f7349c970e0fadb7ec1d3c1086/contracts/SwapRouter.sol#L22).

Uni v2 and v3 are totally different. It's not possible to easily compute amount of token out simply from reserves using the k = x * y formula because the liquidity is distributed across ticks.

Comment: thank your for the information, I haven't read it carefully.